# Split a string to dictionary C#

Tags: string, dictionary, split

C#
I have a string:

```
string="0x01,abc";
```

I want this string to be added in a dictionary:

```
0x01,abc
```

*where key=0x01, value=abc*
How to do it simply?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` method.

```
string[] tokens = str.Split(',');
```

Your `key = tokens[0];` and `value = tokens[1];`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it for string as below,

```
string str = "0x01,abc";

IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { str.Split(',')[0], str.Split(',')[1] }
};
```

or 
if you need to do this on string array, you can follow this approach

```
string[] str = new string[] {"0x01,abc", "0x02,abcd" };

IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach(var s in str)
    dict.Add(s.Split(',')[0], s.Split(',')[1]);
```

Comment: What if I say i need to store it in a dictionary <byte, string> ?

Comment: /// you cannot covert string to byte instead you can convert to byte[]
  string str = "0x01,abc";
  byte[] bstr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.Split(',')[0]);
  
  IDictionary<byte[], string> dict = new Dictionary<byte[], string>()
  {
   { bstr, str.Split(',')[1] }
  };